# How to distribute an in-house app through App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am developing three in-house apps and we want to distribute the apps to 40 iPads. But we dont want them all to be registered as development devices, we want to have the apps in the store. When I tried ad-hoc distribution, it never worked. I tried to install the apps after registering the device.

So I thought is there anyway that we can distribute the in-house apps through app store instead of going through this painful app distribution?

Comment: It wouldn't be through the app store, but your own 'internal' link that apps can be installed from. I'm not totally clear on any details beyond that though...

Comment: Any app you put on the app store is available to anyone. No way you cand do what you want through the app store. Read the answers and find the approach that works for you.

Comment: you can do it if you password protect it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably you would have an Enterprise Developer license ($299/year) which is for exactly the scenario you have: you want to develop and distribute apps to your organization. This type of license exists precisely for this purpose and because Apple doesn't really want these kinds of apps -- apps that are not generally for everyone -- to be on the App Store.

To distribute your apps under this license you need to look at Apple's Mobile Device Management architecture. It basically lets you setup your own legitimate "store" through which your apps would be distributed to your organization's devices. It is not intended for you to sell your apps to the general public, bypassing Apple. No, no.

I cannot seem to find a good link for you. Google for "apple mobile device management documentation" or "apple mdm"; there are a lot of interesting PDFs that come up.

Bottom line is that this is, I think, a fair bit of work to setup this infrastructure. But necessary if you want to do internal app distribution the right way.

Answer (score 2):

https://testflightapp.com/ it's a very good website to distribute Apps to the people you want. You should really check it out.

It's not through App Store, though.

Comment: testflight works great to deliver ad-hoc apps. It definitely has its quirks, but for the most part its a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this documentation from Apple, should provide you with the necessary information for in-house distribution: http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/#app43ad6a6a

Answer (score 0):

My organization has had some luck using [MobileIron](http://www.mobileiron.com/en/multi-os-management/ios-management/overview). I believe the piece is called "Enterprise App Storefront". 
You setup a MobileIron server and (one option is to) get a MobileIron-managed app directly from the App Store to connect up to it.