# How to Store Username and password in Keychain and verify them through alertView

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to store a username and password in keychain and verify them through an alertview. Does anyone have code for that?

I am doing this because the apps are in-house and I want my apps to be accepted by app store.

Comment: Please stop using `xcode` tag if it's programming related question. Removed your tag.

Comment: What have you tried? Most people aren't willing to just hand over source to anyone who asks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338007/how-to-use-keychain-in-iphone-application-for-store-the-username-and-password-an?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *username = @"yourUserName";
NSString *password = @"yourPassword";
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"TestAppLoginData" accessGroup:nil];

// Store username to keychain
[keychain setObject:username forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];

// Store password to keychain
[keychain setObject:password forKey:(id)kSecValueData]; 


// Get username from keychain (if it exists)
NSString *username = [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
NSLog(@"username: %@", username);


// Get password from keychain (if it exists)  
NSString *password = [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData];
NSLog(@"password: %@", password);
```

Download `KeychainItemWrapper` form [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: I am new to iOS development. Here Should I initialize username and password as NSString and instead of "text" I should enter the text I wanted?

Comment: @G-Man I have edited my answer. And for more you can check the [example here](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html)

Comment: I added this KeyChainItemWrapper.h to my project but I am getting 20 errors saying "Semantic Issue 'release' is unavailable'. Just by adding the header file.

Comment: It is because you are using ARC. Please remove all `release'  calls

Comment: May I know how to remove them?

Comment: Ok, I am saving username and password to keychain and using alertview to compare them when the app starts. Is it enough for the app store?

Comment: Yep I think so. Just submit to app store and verify the result :)