# In-house app rejected in app store

Tags: iphone, ios, distribution

I have submitted three in-house apps to app store with the username and password requirement to access the app. But it was rejected the second time. I followed the solutions offered here in the following posts,

[Alternative solutions for in-house iPhone enterprise app distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309835/alternative-solutions-for-in-house-iphone-enterprise-app-distribution/3790758#3790758)

[iPad in-house App distribution through App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965308/ipad-in-house-app-distribution-through-app-store)

I used an alertview to ask for username and password. Username and password are saved in keychain. My applications are single window applications that doesn't require internet connection. How can I submit my app to the app store? Some suggest implementing php username and login for the app. How can I accomplish that? Can anyone give an explanation ?

Reason I have got from Apple:

> We found that your app is an in-house application, intended for
>   employees or members of your organization. As such, it is not
>   appropriate for the App Store.
>
> For information on distributing proprietary, in-house applications,
>   please refer to the iOS Developer Enterprise Program.
>
> If you cannot - or choose not to - revise your app to be in compliance
>   with the App Store Review Guidelines, you may wish to build an HTML5
>   web app instead. You can distribute web apps directly on your web
>   site; the App Store does not accept or distribute web apps.
>
> HTML5 is the major new version of HTML and enables audio and video to
>   play natively in the browser without requiring proprietary plug-ins.
>   Using HTML5, web apps can look and behave like native iPhone and iPad
>   apps, and using HTML5's Offline Application Cache, a web app can work
>   even when the device is offline. With web apps, you have flexibility
>   to deliver as much or as little functionality as you desire.
>
> To get started with iPhone or iPad web apps, please review Getting
>   Started with iPhone Web Apps.
>
> For a description of the HTML elements and attributes you can use in
>   Safari on iPhone, check out Safari HTML Reference: Introduction.

Comment: It would help if you posted the reason Apple rejected the app.

Comment: Could you just use ad-hoc distribution, for up to 100 people? Apple sometimes frowns upon in-house apps.

Comment: @MarkRobinson My university doesn't want to send me their device ids to access the app every time. Because I have to generate a certificate for each new id and send them the app.

Comment: @user1825440 Why did apple reject your app, could you give us the exact text?

Comment: @MarkRobinson I have added the exact reason they gave me in the question. Please check it

Comment: @user1825440 Why haven't you used the Enterprise program?

Comment: @rmaddy Its expensive. So my manager told me to find a way not to use it

Comment: @user1825440 It is the only way apple is going to let you use. It is however only $300 a year.

Comment: I bet it's cheaper than the time and expense wasted with not using the Enterprise program. How come no one ever has the money to do something the right way once but they always have more money to do it the wrong way several times?

Comment: @rmaddy ok now, getting more than 12,000 points doesn't make you a person who can pass judgments on the people who ask questions. Thanks for your suggestions anyway

Comment: @user1825440 I'm not passing judgement on you. I'm making an observation based on over 25 years of real world software development. You're spending way more than the $200 difference for the Enterprise program by trying to avoid paying for the Enterprise program. Believe me, I've seen untold amounts of money wasted in the long term trying to save money in the short term. I hope you work this out one way or another.

Answer (score 3):

Just as Apple suggested, you should look into the iOS Developer Enterprise Program.  It is created specifically to work for in-house app development.

With an enterprise distribution profile and certificate, you can create .ipa files that can be installed on any device, with no need to get the device IDs of all devices you plan to install it on beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

This line says it all,

> We found that your app is an in-house application, intended for employees or members of your organization. As such, it is not appropriate for the App Store.
>
> For information on distributing proprietary, in-house applications, please refer to the iOS Developer Enterprise Program.

They don't want in-house apps on the store, they want you to use their enterprise program.

Apple as a company wants to make the most money and for them they limit this method to make more money. However it is only $300.

University (i think it's similar to Enterprise but for academic institution) will not work since it requires the device id's like ad-hoc.

Comment: no denying apple wants to make money but i think this one is mostly about not cluttering the app store with apps that are useless to the vast majority of users

Comment: @wattson12 Probably so, that would seem equally important.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 3 programs are available:

- **Developer**, to submit to App Store only
- **Enterprise** only for in-house distribution, ie in your company limited to your employees and not for App Store
- **University** (i think it's similar to Enterprise but for academic institution)

To confirm you strongly that you cannot use Enterprise as you wish, i can tell you that when my company subscribed Enterprise Program, someone from Apple phone me asking if I understood that Enterprise license does not allowed to submit on the App Store.